# Add a page under a taxonomy with same URL structure in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am attempting to create some posts to display on a CPT taxonomy page which follow the same URL structure.

I have a post type of **animal** and taxonomy of **animal-category**, the generated URLs for these pages are:

- **domain.com/animal**
- **domain.com/animal-category**

I then want to create a standard page (not part of this post type) which will have the URL:

- **domain.com/animal-category/page-name**

*Structurally* the page is unrelated to the animal posts and could be a standard page or in a post type, it doesn't matter.

After research and previous knowledge I cannot find a rewrite rule to force a page to use **domain.com/animal-category** before the page-name is added - as it has already been rewritten for the taxonomy.

Maybe there is a completely different solution to achieve having a page (with this URL structure) on a taxonomy listing?

Comment: Is the taxonomy you are referring is fixed or that also a variable for different different pages ?

Comment: I was attempting to create a page which you would relate to one of the taxonomies at which point it would rewrite the URL. I can do the relationship but cannot rewrite the URL to have the start of the URL the same as the taxonomy URL. The taxonomies could be dog, cat, horse.

Comment: This guide: https://wpza.net/custom-post-type-and-page-share-the-same-url/ provides some different options on how to solve this. One is by disabling the archive, another is by changing the page's slug and the third is by changing the CPT's slug (whilst maintaining the posts).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found is to use the [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) hook.

```php
/**
 * Customize specific post_type parameter and replace it with an existing page
 * 
 * @param $query
 * @return void
*/
function so41567823_customize_query($query) {

    // Check if request is for post_type and equals page name
    if (isset($query->query_vars['animal']) 
        && 'animal-category' === $query->query_vars['animal']) {

        // Set page name
        $query->query_vars['pagename'] = 'animal-category';

        // Unset post_type vars
        unset($query->query_vars['post_type']);
        unset($query->query_vars['animal']);
        unset($query->query_vars['name']);

    }

}

add_action('parse_request', 'so41567823_customize_query');
```

---

Source: [Custom Rewrite rule to match anything not already matched by WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/301423/74281)

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that :)

1. In your theme create the animal-taxonomy template and name it `taxonomy-animal-category.php`
2. In the loop, apply a condition to get the displayed item (queried object) as follows:

   ```php
    $queried_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;

    if($queried_slug=="page-name"){ 

        // IT IS THE PAGE we have

    } else { 

        if( have_posts() ){

            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;

        } else {

             echo "NO animals found :)";

        }

    }
   ```

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood - the above code you have written will show page content on domain.com/animal-category/ if it exists, if not it will display the category. I want to relate pages to the animal-category which have the same URL structure e.g. domain.com/animal-category/page-name, I would then use the template you are using above to show the links to those pages on the category itself.

Answer (score 0):

I will take your desired URL to be as following,

```
http://example.com/%taxonomy%/page-name
```

Please have a look at the filter [_get_page_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_get_page_link/). Though this filter is not intended to use with theme or plugin development, you can use it to achieve your task.

So use it as follows,

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'custom_rewrite_rules' ), 1, 0 ); 
/*
* Rewrite page urls
* adding prefix to page urls
*/
function custom_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%taxonomy%", '([^/]+)', 'taxonomy=' );
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root. '%taxonomy%/%pagename%';        
}
```

Above function will create the desired url. Now use the filter to change `%taxonomy%` to your value.

```
add_filter( '_get_page_link', 'custom_taxonomy_page_link', 10, 2 );
function custom_taxonomy_page_link( $link, $post_id ) {
    $link = str_replace('%taxonomy%', 'animal-category', $link);
    return $link;
}
```

This is not tested properly, but with little research it might help you.